# $_FILE does not work every time when uploading an Image

Tags: php, arrays, image, file-upload

so I have been stuck with this problem for quite some time and I have just ignored it until it is becoming a bigger issue. When uploading an image, about 80% of the times it will upload it and detect it, but that other 20% will randomly not detect the image (its always the same image). I took 4 random pictures with my phone, 2 of them upload fine, and the other 2 get an error.

using `print_r($_FILES)` - it shows me where I am getting the error for the two pictures, but I don't have a clue how to fix this.

ERROR upload files (2 examples):

```
Array([file]=>Array([name]=>1.jpg **[type]=>[tmp_name]=>[error]=>1** [size]=>0))

Array([file]=>Array([name]=>2015-07-31 16.25.59-1.jpg **[type]=> [tmp_name] => [error]=>1**[size]=>0))
```

CORRECT upload files (2 examples):

```
Array([file] => Array ( [name] => 2015-07-31 16.26.43-1.jpg **[type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpFB57.tmp [error] => 0** [size] => 1871686 ) )

Array([file] => Array ( [name] => 2015-07-31 16.26.22.jpg **[type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php5FDF.tmp [error] => 0** [size] => 1747067 ) )
```

Looking at the ERROR upload, it is detecting an error due to the tmp_name issuing a type to it, it is just blank. (I bolded it)

How come some of my images are not uploading doing the exact same thing while some upload? (using same camera - all landscape photos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because your file's size is bigger than `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: Also check `post_max_size`. The **smaller** of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` will determine your maximum upload size.

Comment: I right-clicked on my images properties sizes:
(error pictures) - #1 2.51 MB  #2 2.11 MB 
(uploaded pictures) - #1 1.78 MB  #2 1.66 MB 

Is it possible for me to increase the upload_max_filesize? the file is uploading to a FTP server if that helps to increase the size

Comment: if you don't have direct access to php.ini try using `ini_set` in the very beginning of the script. Set `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to something like `10M`

Comment: You can't set upload_max_filesize using ini_set() because upload_max_filesize is a PHP_INI_PERDIR and i just tried it again setting it to 4M, 8M, 10M and it did not help.

I will see if I have direct access to php.ini. I am using Netbeans Developers  IDE

Comment: oops, you're right. That was doable in older versions of php.

Comment: WOO! I searched my computer for the php.ini file and then searched for 'upload_max_filesize'. changed it from 2M to 10M. reset everything and works like a charm :)! Thank you everyone!!